Domain name expired but whois ok
I’m trying to help my partners business out and I’ve got an interesting one but also very weird.
They’ve got a .com domain name that when we look on their control panel has expired but when I look at the whois register the expiration date is a year after, almost like it was renewed and the domain status shows ok. Unfortunately we can't find a payment for the renewal and it doesn't look like they were invoiced.
They’re saying that they can't re-instate it most likely as it expired on their control panel 5 months ago. All the DNS resolves correctly and the admin contacts haven’t been changed. Further to this they would have noticed they were in a grace period as their email addresses would have been taken offline when it went into it’s second grace period.
There is some confusion that it might have been transferred but when I look at the who is the registrar it’s still the original.
Despite this they have given me a EEP Auth code to initiate the transfer to another registrar. My concern with this is that the original registrar might put the domain name on registry hold and then the DNS etc will then stop.
Any thoughts and advice would be greatly appreciated.

If you are looking up an un-cached and authoritative whois e.g. icann, then that is the correct information.  If the registrar doesn't honour your transfer, complain to the registry.

Have you used the ICANN Lookup tool? Check there what the "Domain Status" is. Then you can check what the status means.
